# Why does this regex returns true?

Tags: php, regex

Since regex is not my best side i need help from you guys. So i have this line in my PHP code

```
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if(preg_match('/|google|robot|bot|spider|crawler|curl|Facebot|facebook|archiver|^$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
   var_dump('returning true!');
   return true;
}
die('end');
```

And this is output of both var_dumps

```
string(121) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"

string(15) "returning true!"
```

The question is why this is returning true and how to write it proper way so it will work as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is invalid:

```
|google|robot|bot|spider|crawler|curl|Facebot|facebook|archiver|^$
^
|
+--- this character (an alternator) effectively renders the regex useless
```

This means that the regex could in theory match anything because the left part is empty.

Moreover, `^$` on the right of the last alternator also means an empty string match.

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4q2m9j1y71bNaA8x)

Comment: so should i also remove ^$ ?

Comment: Yes indeed, though it seems like on debuggex, these two characters don't participate in the matching at all, so they don't match an empty string. Either way they're useless.

Answer (score 5):

Because the start of your pattern match the empty string:

```
/|google...
```

That means: nothing OR google ...